# Tensorboard graph messy (readvariableop_resource nodes) using tf.summay.trace_export

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

The code bellow build two tensorboard graphs for the same model, while using Keras API build nice simple graph, using tf.summary.trace_export() add **for each variable define in the graph** a node in the external scope with the suffix "readvariableop_resource", which make the graph be really messy as the number of the parameters increase.
(In the example below we have 2 dense layer each one have 2 variable (kernel and bias) total 4 variables (4 nodes))

```
from datetime import datetime

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


# Define the model.
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'])

(train_images, train_labels), _ = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
train_images = train_images / 255.0

# Define the Keras TensorBoard callback.
logdir="logs/fit/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)

# Train the model.
model.fit(
    train_images,
    train_labels,
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=1,
    callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])


@tf.function
def traceme(x):
    return model(x)

logdir="logs/fit1/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)
tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True)
# Forward pass
traceme(tf.zeros((1, 28, 28, 1)))
with writer.as_default():
    tf.summary.trace_export(name="model_trace", step=0)
```

[image]